# Linux: Duplicate network interface to simulate link failures

Tags: linux, networking, interface

I run Ubuntu. I need to add some latency and/or some network errors to see if my application can handle with network failure ( connecting & disconnecting ). I found "tc" tool which will be helpful to add latency and make the interface more faulty. My concern is that tc will affect my eth0, which is not good, cause I need to have connection with network and Kerberos. Is it possible to "copy" a link and simulate network problems only on "copy" of network interface?

If yes, what is the tool/technique?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest implementation for what your thinking about here is a VPN connection. It creates a virtual adapter that can work alongside the physical one. Linux supports [Open VPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) which seems pretty well suited to the problem your describing.
You might consider moving your development environment onto a virtual machine, which would allow you to more easily test things like latency and bandwidth without interfering with the mundane function of yout desktop machine.